# Python скриншот неактивного окна OSX

Tags: python, macos, screenshots

Мне нужно делать регулярные скриншоты открытых неактивных окон с помощью Python3 в win и mac.

Для win нашел [такой вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695214/python-screenshot-of-inactive-window-printwindow-win32gui), в нем используются win32 библиотеки.

Есть ли подобные библиотеки под macOS?
Или знает кто-нибудь другой способ?